# github actions runner/work directory does not exist in local machine

Tags: github-actions, runner

i am trying to craete ci cd for my self-hosted node js server. server is running on ec2. But i can not see the /home/runner/work folder when i connect from ssh. github actions logs showing that directory but it is not exist.

Comment: https://github.com/Sysinternals/ProcMon-for-Linux You might try to see what happens under the hood with this tool.